# Do people become resistant to stinging nettles?

Tags: biology, plants

The WikiHow page [How to Touch Nettles Without Stinging Yourself](https://www.wikihow.com/Touch-Nettles-Without-Stinging-Yourself) claims:

> Although experienced nettle harvesters often go bare-handed, this isn't just because they know how to avoid stings. **Many of them have become resistant to the stings over years of exposure**, while others enjoy the sensation.

This is one of my childhood mysteries which I was never able to fully explain - my neighbour could pick stinging nettles without apparent pain.

Does common contact with stinging nettles confer a resistance to the sting, and thus avoid pain?

Comment: I think an apologist for Jane Goodall once made a similar claim, but I can't find it.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm What do you mean by "an apologist for" in this context?

Comment: @gerrit someone who defended her use of stinging nettles on poachers.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Do you mean Dian Fossey and not Jane Goodall?

Comment: I can tell you from personal experience that this is true, at least on a temporary basis, but anecdote is not citable evidence!

Comment: @JackAidley Sorry, yes I did!